# Could not find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)

Tags: curl

I'm trying to compile synergy from the source code, and when I do, I get this error:

```
-- Could not find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:160 (messege):
Missing library: curl
```

So I did

```
sudo apt-get install curl
sudo apt-get install curl_library
sudo apt-get install curl_include_dir
```

and I still get the same error as before.

For some extra info, I'm following along with this guide here and just got past the X11 step: http://www.rootusers.com/compiling-synergy-from-source-on-the-raspberry-pi/

Comment: try `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 19):

The names of the packages for programs and libraries in Debian (and Raspbian) are standardized, and sometimes differ from the names the libraries give themselves or the tag or symbol names for them.

You should search for "curl" on the package system, and you will find the curl-related libraries, which might be what you want.

Packages ending with a "-dev" are the ones you usually need when you want to have something compiled, they will install the includes and other files needed for that.

Try a:

> apt-cache search curl

To find out all the packages with "curl" in the package name.

You are probably looking for one of these:

> libcurl3 - easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (OpenSSL flavour)
>
> libcurl3-dbg - debugging symbols for libcurl (OpenSSL, GnuTLS and NSS flavours)
>
> libcurl3-gnutls - easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (GnuTLS flavour)
>
> libcurl3-nss - easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (NSS flavour)
>
> libcurl4-gnutls-dev - development files and documentation for libcurl (GnuTLS flavour)
>
> libcurl4-nss-dev - development files and documentation for libcurl (NSS flavour)
>
> libcurl4-openssl-dev - development files and documentation for libcurl (OpenSSL flavour)

I would try to get the last one, the openssl-dev.

> apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev

And then try to compile the software again. If that doesn't work, try to install the "libcurl3" as a second option.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev` also works on ubuntu for `cmake`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. To make it short:

Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

CentOS:

```
sudo yum install libcurl-devel
```